# If six points of an elliptic curve are contained in a conic, then their sum is $O$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves

Let $C$ be a projective cubic without singular points and $O\in C$ an inflexion point. We consider the addition in $C$ with $O$ as neutral element. If $R_{1},...,R_{6}\in C$ are different points such that there exists a conic that contains all of them, then $R_{1}+...+R_{6}=O$.

I think I have to use Pappus/Pascal's theorem (depending on the irreducibility of the conic) and the next result:

$a,b,c\in C$ lie on the same line if and only if $a+b+c=O$.

The thing is that I do not know how to combine them to solve the exercise.

Observation: This exercise is a particular case of theorem 9.2. of chapter 6 in Walker's algebraic curves book, but I would like to use more elementary tools.

Comment: I might approach this by identifying the group of an elliptic curve with its Picard group, temporarily using the point at infinity as the neutral element. The divisor $D$ associated with that quadratic is principal, and its only pole (of order $\le6$) is at the point at infinity $O_\infty$. The assumptions then imply that $D=1\cdot R_1+\cdots+1\cdot R_6-6\cdot O_\infty$ proving the claim for that group law. A point of inflection is of order three, so replacing $O_\infty$ with $O$ does not change things.

Comment: But, doing this with Pappus/Pascal is surely more fun! I don't see it right away.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but this exercise has came up in an algebraic curves course and I do not know all those things about elliptic curves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $R_1, \ldots, R_6$ be distinct points on $C$. Choose three pairs of them, form the corresponding straight lines and call $C'$ the reducible cubic consisting of such lines. Consider the linear system of cubics passing through the 9 points in the intersection of $C$ with $C'$. Then, if $R_1, \ldots, R_6$ lie on a conic $K$, we have a reducible cubic consisting of $K$ and a straight line $r$ passing through the remaining 3 points in the intersection.
The sum of all 9 points is 0 and the sum of the three points in $r$ is 0, hence the thesis follows.

Comment: You rely on the [Cayley-Bacharach](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley-Bacharach_theorem) theorem here right?